# Applying a scroll action to one element will affect the other?

Tags: jquery, scroll, element

[image]

I wanted to create it using scroll action.

If it appears in drop-down form in the menu, I wanted to push the other elements down.
as shown in the picture above.

but, I found that the code I created does not affect other elements when one element moves.
Is there a problem with the position attribute?
Is there an answer to this?
Also, I can't move if I tie it with div class, do you know why?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwpg018241/x3uezs2d/19/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 600 && $(document).scrollTop() < 1200) {
      $("p").addClass("hz", 1000, "easeInOutQuad");
    } else {
      $("p").removeClass("hz", 1000, "easeInOutQuad");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hz {
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.mobile_text {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  left: 20px
}

p {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  left: 20px;
  top: -80px;
  opacity: 1;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body style="height:2500px;">
  <div class="mobile_text">
    <h1>01. MENU</h1>
    <p 01>moving element<br> moving element<br> moving element<br></p>
    <h1>02. MENU</h1>
    <p 02>moving element<br> moving element<br> moving element<br></p>
    <h1>03. MENU</h1>
    <p 03>moving element<br> moving element<br> moving element<br></p>
    <h1>04. MENU</h1>
    <h1>05. MENU</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried all the positions, but it didn't work as I expected...

Comment: One solution would be to add/remove `display:block` - as it's on your `p`, it pushes the other menus down - if you only add it to .hz then the menus won't be pushed down until the p's are shown.   jquery adds/removes display:block with .slideDown/.slideUp, so here's one (jquery) solution:  http://jsfiddle.net/ghka9r2q/  .stop is needed as otherwise the slides queue up as they do in your original - doesn't make it very nice though, it's just a starter showing use of display:block.

Comment: Thank you very much for suggesting a good solution.!!